# Can I use "in-need patients" instead of "patients in need"?

Tags: attributives

I saw too many that people say "at-risk patients" instead of "patients at risk" and "out-of-date books" instead of "books which are out of date".

Can I say "in-need patients" instead of "patients in need"?

Comment: As a general principle, preposition-based phrases don't usually work well as attributive adjectives (used *before* the noun). Note that with *out-of-date books* and *at-risk patients* you have to include hyphens in the written form that wouldn't be relevant when saying the books are out of date, or the patients at risk. Some people will accept a reference to *in-need patients,* but I personally don't like it. I think it's "jargonny", and would strongly advise you to stick with uncontentious *patients [who are] in need*.

Comment: This question would really benefit from you including the examples of this use that you found while researching it. You could link to a couple of web sites that used this kind of structure.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - re 'jargonny' - YES. Kingsley Amis, in _The Kings English_ ('by turns reflective, acerbic and provocative') inveighs strongly against what he calls 'Germanisms' ('clumsy attempts to stick labels on arbitrary groupings: _never-before-told incidents/a more-honored-in-the-breach situation/a let-the-devil-take-the-hindmost attitude_'). He says 'If we wish to protect ourselves from this new assault on our wits, we must begin by avoiding every form of easy compounding'

Comment: @FumbleFingers - isn't there a 'rule' that compound adjectives need to be hyphenated when they are placed before a noun, but not after, thus _my often- drunk mother frequently falls over_,  but _my mother, often drunk, frequently falls over_?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Well, that's just an orthographic convention - that's [not always rigorously applied.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lily+white+skin%2Clily-white+skin%2Clilywhite+skin&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) If you toggle between AmE / /BrE corpuses on that link, you'll see that *Americans* (normally more fastidious than Brits in such matters) actually write unhyphenated ***lily white skin*** significantly more often than we do. And "nonce-word" attributive adjectives are often enclosed in scare quotes to alert readers to "unusual" usages.

Comment: ...I don't exactly side with Amis on this point, though. It gives fluent speakers useful extra flexibility in their choice of phrasing. But *on average* I'd advise learners to avoid them, the same as I'd advise avoiding wordplay and other creative use of language. Such things are too difficult to learn and get exactly right, and too noticeable when something that seems obvious and witty in your *own* language simply doesn't "translate" smoothly into English!

Comment: Attributive ***in-need*** is a slightly awkward one, imho. Mainstream Anglophones don't much like ***needful*** (common in Indian English), and ***needy*** has taken on the specific sense of ***emotionally insecure / demanding***, so we don't have an obviously suitable form for the attributive use. I'm not sure how useful it is anyway though - surely *by definition*, if you're a "patient", you're in need of some kind of treatment. Maybe something like ***urgent*** or ***critical*** is relevant herre.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I am have an awkward relationship with Amis, both _père et fils_; I am in awe of their ability, but often horrified at their opinions.

Comment: Wow, @FumbleFingers, it’s rare that I see us Americans described as fastidious… about anything :-)

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum: Well, we can't exactly say Webster's spelling reforms were an unmitigated success, but Merriam-Webster (and the Bible, of course) have fairly high status as "authorities / exemplars" in the US. Things may be changing *very* recently, but I think the relatively higher proportion of non-native Anglophones in the US tends to increase pressure for their *children* to know and use English "properly" (as opposed to "fluently", which most of them would do automatically, if they're *born* in the US).

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum - _It is considered unctuous by fastidious Americans — and by all of England, who attacked the Duchess of Cambridge’s mother for saying it upon first meeting the queen._ - Washington Post Miss Manners column ('It' is saying 'Pleased to meet you' upon being introduced to someone, and not 'How do you do').

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum - _By the 1890s, Wrigley’s had introduced a whole line of chewing gums, including Wrigley’s Spearmint. In 1914 it added Doublemint gum to the mix. Around the same time, Pep-O-Mint Lifesavers were invented. Wint-O-Green, Cl-O-ve, Lic-O-Rice, Vi-O-let, and Cinn-O-Mon soon joined the family of "mints," and ads began targeting **fastidious Americans** worried about their breath._ [A Brief History of Mint](https://next.voxcreative.com/sponsored/10709952/a-brief-history-of-mint-from-air-freshener-to-breath-freshener)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I’m sorry if my self-depreciation was unclearly formulated. I didn’t mean that no American is ever described as fastidious (Hell, I myself have been described in more Anglo-Saxon variants). I was riffing off of FumbleFingers’s remark that Americans **as a group** are “normally more fastidious than Brits” about such punctuational niceties. I think of us as a nation capable of the most profound inanities and rhetorical sloppiness.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum - it was clearly formulated. I should apologise that my light-hearted intent was, perhaps, not. I think that all English speaking nations are equally capable of inanity and sloppiness.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Nice to meet you.

Comment: Instead of just giving the OP the basics: patients at risk versus at-risk patients, you guys got into all this stuff that is of no interest to the OP (probably) and then closed the question. My goodness. Too many questions are being closed like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to warn that this kind of construction can only work when the meaning is clear from convention or context. "In need" usually means "needy," i.e. not having much money. "At risk," when used in schools, often describes the same demographic, but the "risk" is usually something like "they're at risk of dropping out of school or getting failing grades or being limited by school disciplines."

In medical contexts, these could have other meanings. Medical "risk" often means the risk of dying, or of developing various medical problems, like being "at risk" for cancer. But [this official definition](https://aspr.hhs.gov/at-risk/Pages/default.aspx) overlaps these medical risks with some of the same sociological risks:

> At-risk individuals are people with access and functional needs (temporary or permanent) that may interfere with their ability to access or receive medical care before, during, or after a disaster or public health emergency.
> Examples of at-risk populations may include but are not limited to children, pregnant women, older adults, people with disabilities, people from diverse cultures, people with limited English proficiency, people with limited access to transportation, people with limited access to financial resources, people experiencing homelessness, people who have chronic health conditions, and people who have pharmacological dependency.

Similarly, "in need" could have specific medical senses, like "in need of an urgent organ transplant."

So if your primary meaning is "not having much money," I'd encourage you to use a more specific term. The word "needy" is a handy version of "in need." But there are philosophical reasons to choose other terms. "In need" says that this person is not complete or sufficient; their economic state is a problem to be solved. This might be true in the moment (especially if medical bills are involved!), but it's an emotive and somewhat patronizing tone. A more objective term, like the one in the quote above, "people with limited access to financial resources," might be better. Another common one is "low [socioeconomic status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socioeconomic_status)"; this can address both financial challenge as well as other inequities.

Answer (score -1):

As @FumbleFingers said, preposition-based phrases don't usually work well as attributive adjectives.  The phrase
[*in-need* (attributive) is much less common in this sense than *in need* (predicative)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28patients+in+need+*+0.1%29%2Cin-need+_NOUN_%2Cin-need+patients&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) even when compared to just *patients in need*.  Please note a factor is already applied to the latter.

Also, *in-need patients* is not found.

Of the [top usages of *in-need*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28patients+in+need+*+0.1%29%2Cin-need+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) described above, only two are paired with nouns, *society* and *population*.

Hence we should stay with the construction *patients in need* or *patients who are in need*.